# When l'Hospital doesn't seem to do the trick

Tags: calculus, limits

**Problem.**

Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^{-x^2}$$

Notice that this is equal to $$\lim{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{e^{-x^2}}{1}}{{x}}$$

But using l'Hospital here only gives infinitely many undefined results by every derivative!

How to understand this?

Comment: Instead, write $x/e^{x^2}$.

Comment: Ah! Eureka....!

Answer (score 3):

Try rewriting the limit: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} x e^{-x^2}\quad = \quad\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{x}{e^{x^2}} \quad \overset{L'H}{=} \quad \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{2xe^{x^2}} = \;\cdots \;?$$